# Material-ui table pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-ui table for listing data. table will load all data at once from remote server. Is there any way to load data through pagination, as page changes data has to be fetched from remote.

when page loads i will get data from following code.

```
const options = { method: 'GET', headers: { Origin: '*' } };
    fetch(`https://some-url/user_groups`, options)
        .then(function (result) {
           //i will get data here
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error while fetching ', error));
```

Comment: Where are you getting your data from? And how are you getting it? A way to do it would be to filter your fetchData function limiting the number of values you retrieve based on the page you're accessing. Without more info it's difficult to help more.

Comment: Could you tell us what you tried, how you current fetch data, some could would help understand the issue and then help you out!

Comment: i can get data based on limiting number of values. but in material-ui there is no option to get data using pagination

Answer (score 2):

Follow following steps:

Step 1. Change the server side to return only 1 page of data, and also return number of available records.

```
/api/getData?offset=5&limit=10
```

Step 2. On your react components, or redux store, create following state:

```
{
    data: list of data item to display on the table
    page: the current page of the table
    resultCount: number of available records
}
```

Step 3. Implement `loadData` to load the current page of data & result count.

Step 4. On component mount & page change event, reload the data.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can by adding condition to the pagination slicing logic

```
rows.slice((useDbPagination ? 0 : page) * rowsPerPage,
           (useDbPagination ? 0 : page) * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(/*render row here*/);
```